# center one div inside of another div - align the centers

Tags: css

I am creating a tab with rotated text - I'm trying to center one div inside another, however I want the centers of the divs to be aligned but I'm getting alignment issues:

```
<div class="tileStrip" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:185px;background:#DDDDDD;">
    <div class ="clickToSlide" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:30px;background:#AAAAAA">
     <div style="position:relative;top:50%">    
       <span style="    font-weight:bold;color:white;-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);display:block;">International</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I center one div inside a larger parent div vertically so that my rotated text is centered?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jHrEm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transformations rotate elements by their center point, so you need to position the center of your `<span>` to the center of your sidebar before the transformations.

First of all, you don't need the `top:50%` wrapper div, you can do it all on the span.

- Before the transformations and any additional styles, your span will appear in the top left corner of your sidebar.
- Add `width:500px`. In order to accurately position the center, the span must be fixed width, say 500px. We assume no text will ever be longer than that.
- Add `text-align:center`. Now the text is correctly centered in our fixed width span, although the span itself is in the wrong position.
- Add `position:relative`, so we can tweak the position of the span relative to its original position.
- Add `top:50%` and `margin-top:-10px`. As 50% sets the top edge, we need to compensate with a negative top margin to center the span vertically. 10px is half of the span's height.
- Add `left:50%` and `margin-left:-250px`, same as above, centers the span horizontally. 250px is half of the span's fixed width.
- Finally add your transformations, and it should be properly centered.

Resulting HTML:

```
<div class="tileStrip" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:185px;background:#DDDDDD;">
    <div class ="clickToSlide" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:30px;background:#AAAAAA">
       <span style="font-weight:bold;color:white;display:block;text-align:center;width:500px;position:relative;top:50%;margin-top:-10px;left:50%;margin-left:-250px;-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);">International</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jHrEm/7/

Comment: I have read many solutions to this problem around the web, and this solution is by far the best! Good work!

Comment: One thing to notice is that since clickToScale is positioned absolutely, you'll need to add `margin-left:30px` on the next sibling in the titleStrip div.

Comment: And adding `overflow: hidden` to clickToSlide helps you prevent empty scrolling in the bottom of your document.